# Angular Factory "Cannot read property 'property' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using Angular 1.6.x

Having a really hard time getting a Factory to work with a login submit

**login.controller.js**

```
angular.module('appName').controller('LoginController',[
  '$scope',
  function($scope, Login){
    $scope.submitLogin = function(){
      console.log('login requested');
      Login.login();
    }
  }]);
```

**login.factory.js**

```
angular.module('appName').factory('Login', function (){
  var service = {};

  service.login = function(){
    console.log('Login Factory');
  }

  return service;
});
```

The error I'm getting is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'login' of undefined`

From all the examples I've looked at I'm injecting the factory into the controller, created an object in the factory, and returning that object back. What am I missing here?

Another question to is why am I unable to include the factory in my controller via?

```
angular.module('appName').controller('LoginController',[
  '$scope',
  Login, // <<<<<< This throws an error (scripts.min.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Login is not defined)
  function($scope, Login){
    $scope.submitLogin = function(){
      console.log('login requested');
      Login.login();
    }
  }]);
```

The reason I'm injecting this way is to eliminate the possibilities of errors during minification.

**Edit**

Question answered with injecting Factory with Quotes.

```
angular.module('appName').controller('LoginController',[
  '$scope',
  'Login', // <<<< Was not using quotes
  function($scope, Login){
    $scope.submitLogin = function(){
      console.log('login requested');
      Login.login();
    }
  }]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to inject `Login` factory and wrap it within quotes `'Login'`:

```
'$scope', 'Login',
function($scope, Login){
```

Comment: Could have sworn I tried doing that and it was still failing. But, that worked thank you.

Comment: Seems to me you were not wrapping it in quotes.

Comment: @Full-Hybrid that is the real game here some think who posted first is not a good answer.

Comment: @Jai Probably because you dint include the part factory and wrap it within quotes 'Login': initally

Comment: @Sajeetharan do you think that is really required for such missing thing?

Answer (score 1):

```
angular.module('appName').controller('LoginController',[
  '$scope',
  'Login', // <<<<<< you should inject within quotes
    $scope.submitLogin = function(){
      console.log('login requested');
      Login.login();
    }
  }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose the `factoryName` within `single quotes`

```
angular.module('appName').controller('LoginController',[
  '$scope',
  'Login', // Change hereReferenceError: Login is not defined)
  function($scope, Login){
    $scope.submitLogin = function(){
      console.log('login requested');
      Login.login();
    }
  }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be, You are missing **`''`**

```
angular.module('appName').controller('LoginController',[
  '$scope',
  'Login',
  function($scope, Login){

  }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also note that the **order** of your injections with **quotes** needs to be consistent with the **parameters**. For example, the following will still give you an `undefined`:

```
angular.module('appName').controller('LoginController',
  ['$scope', 'Factory1', 'Factory2',
  function($scope, Factory2, Factory1){
     Factory1.something; // undefined
     Factory2.something; // undefined
  }]);
```

You need **follow the sequence**, like this:

```
angular.module('appName').controller('LoginController',
  ['$scope', 'Factory1', 'Factory2',
  function($scope, Factory1, Factory2){
     Factory1.something; // Yay!
     Factory2.something; // Woohoo!
  }]);
```